# Rust, permutations between fixed size, and varying size

Tags: rust

My data is structured this way:

```
[
 (
  permutation_result0, 
  permutation_result1, 
  permutation_result2, 
  (varying_size_values0), 
  (varying_size_values1), 
  (varying_size_values2)
 )
...
]
```

where `permutation_result0` relates to `varying_size_values0` and so on...

Example:

```
[
 (banana, apple, orange, (50, 20, 10), (66), (10, 2, 3))
 (apple, beef, orange, (49), (5), (10, 20))
 (cabbage, beef, apple, (30), (4, 3), (2, 1, 444))
]
```

Desired output:

```
[

 (banana, apple, orange, 50, 66, 10)
 (banana, apple, orange, 50, 66, 2)
 (banana, apple, orange, 50, 66, 3)
 (banana, apple, orange, 20, 66, 10)
 (banana, apple, orange, 20, 66, 2)
...
 (apple, beef, orange, 49, 5, 10)
 (apple, beef, orange, 49, 5, 20)
 (cabbage, beef, apple, 30, 4, 2)
 (cabbage, beef, apple, 30, 4, 1)
...
]
```

or even:

```
[

 (50, 66, 10)
 (50, 66, 2)
...

 (49, 5, 10)
 (49, 5, 20)
...
 (30, 4, 2)
 (30, 4, 1)
...
]
```

The first 3 entries and their values have to stay the same until all the values that can differ in their corresponding varying values, are exhausted.

The best idea I can come up with so far is using `contains`:

```
let mut results_vec = vec![];
for i in data_structure{
    let mut operating_vec = vec![];
    operating_vec.push(
        i.0, i.1, i.2,
        (i.3, i.3.len()), 
        (i.4, i.4.len()), 
        (i.5, i.5.len())
    );


    let mut inside_value_vec = vec![];
    let mut permutations_vec = vec![];
    for i in operating_vec{
        // 1. if all len > 1
        if i.3.1>1 && i.4.1>1 && i.5.1>1 {
            for xxx in i.3.0{
                inside_value_vec.push(xxx);
            };
            for xxxx in i.4.0{
                inside_value_vec.push(xxxx);
            };
            for xxxxx in i.5.0{
                inside_value_vec.push(xxxxx);
            };

            for x in inside_value_vec.iter().permutations(3){
                if i.3.0.contains(x.0)&&
                   i.4.0.contains(x.1)&&
                   i.5.0.contains(x.2){
                       results_vec.push(
                       i.0, i.1, i.2,
                       x.0, x.1, x.2
                       );
                }
            };

        // 2.check if & which values' len == 1
        //problem is I can't do it 1 by 1, I have to check all 3 values for that condition
        //then remember which positions were len = 1 and glue the derived permutations' values accordingly. 

        // 3. else continue ( for 0 len values )
        };
    };
};
```

As per the comments in my code I can't figure out any remotely clean way for the `len == 1` conditionals. I hope this problem is at least somewhat interesting to the reader and that I can receive guidance. Thanks.

Comment: [`iproduct`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/macro.iproduct.html) in the `itertools` crate can help with that.

Comment: What is the type of `data_structure` exactly? The given example is not valid Rust syntax because it contains variable-length tuples.

Comment: that is not permutations, that is product, or a mix of both

Comment: @Thomas the max size of the varying length tuple is 5, I could either stick to a Vec supplying a custom null value, or maybe experiment with creating my own "json-like" data structure using nested structs? I can edit the question with for example `(0, 0, 66, 0, 0)` if that's better?

Comment: I don't see what's special about the `len == 1` case anyway. Just use three nested loops through the three lists and output an entry in the innermost loop.

Comment: `iproduct` solved this issue ; for type clarity throughout my program I've used tuples as well as vectors and it was perfectly fit. could you post the first comment as an answer? I'd like to close the question and award points for a working solution.